# Slicing list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, slice

I need to slice a list of lists:

```
A = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
idx = slice(0,4)
B = A[:][idx]
```

The code above isn't giving me the right output.

What I want is: `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`

Comment: Where did you see the logic in your question being used?  Also why would `slice(0,4)` give you three elements per sublist if it did happen to work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With numpy it is very simple - you could just perform the slice:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: A = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])

In [3]: A[:,:3]
Out[3]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

You could, of course, transform `numpy.array` back to the `list`:

```
In [4]: A[:,:3].tolist()
Out[4]: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 26):

Very rarely using slice objects is easier to read than employing a list comprehension, and this is not one of those cases.

```
>>> A = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
>>> [sublist[:3] for sublist in A]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

This is very clear. For every sublist in `A`, give me the list of the first three elements.

Answer (score 3):

```
A = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]

print [a[:3] for a in A]
```

Using list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

you can use a list comprehension such as: `[x[0:i] for x in A]`
where `i` is 1,2,3 etc based on how many elements you need.

Comment: Why? he needs the first idx elements from each list.

Comment: @WayneWerner correct but I changed the meaning of idx...instead of the slice it's a raw int

Comment: the OP is defining `idx = slice(0,4)`, not `4`.

Comment: fixed to change the name of idx to i

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
>>> [a[slice(0,3)] for a in A]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Or:

```
>>> [list(filter(lambda x: x<=3, a)) for a in A]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: While that *does* solve the OPs problem, I doubt it was what they were going for.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my code:

```
A = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
print(A[0][0:3],A[1][0:3],A[1][0:3])
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this prints what HuckleberryFinn wrote he wanted, he wanted it without mentioning the indices of A, using a slice object for the 2nd dimension. There's an error in your third argument to `print()`.