# How to slice a nested list twice?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

With a nested list like:

```
ex_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I need to be able to slice this list for:

```
[[1, 2], [4, 5]]
```

I've been trying:

```
list(ex_list[:2][:2])
```

but this isn't working. I'm obviously doing something very wrong but haven't been able to find a solution as using commas doesn't work either for some reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [slicing list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436425/slicing-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try using comprehension:
Try:

```
[i[:2] for i in ex_list[:2]]
```

Code:

```
ex_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
print([i[:2] for i in ex_list[:2]])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to slice the elements separately to the outer list; it's better to do the outer list first to avoid unnecessary inner slices.

```
[inner[:2] for inner in ex_list[:2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Is using `numpy` an option?

```
import numpy as np

ex_list = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
print(ex_list[:2,:2].tolist()) # [[1, 2], [4, 5]]
```

The first `:2` slice the outer list, the second slice each one of the inner lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `map`

```py
l = list(map(lambda lst: lst[:2], ex_list))
```

```
print(l)

[[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]]
```

Or with `itemgetter`

```py
from operator import itemgetter

l = list(map(itemgetter(slice(0,2)), ex_list))
```

```
print(l)

[[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]]
```