# how to get subarray of matrix in python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

say I have the following array `j`:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
 [7, 7, 7, 6, 4], 
 [1, 1, 2, 0, 0]]
```

how can I get the subarray of 2x2 so the subarray would be:

```
[[1, 2], 
 [7, 7],]
```

intuitively I assumed `j[0:2][0:2]` would do the trick but I get:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [7, 7, 7, 6, 4]]
```

Comment: For numpy: `j[:2, :2]`

Comment: @mkrieger1 my fault I read the question wrong - removed the tag

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72025278/how-to-slice-a-nested-list-twice

Comment: Your use of `array`, `subarray` and `matrix` suggest you are using `numpy`.  But the examples are indistinguishable from a list of lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly say what you want from each row:

```
[r[0:2] for r in j[0:2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

in numpy you can do this:

```
import numpy as np 
j = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
 [7, 7, 7, 6, 4], 
 [1, 1, 2, 0, 0]])

j[:2, :2]
```

output:

```
>>
[[1 2]
 [7 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
[j[i][:2] for i in range(2)]

[[1, 2], 
 [7, 7]]
```